# adding 'target' attribute to an element with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add an `target="_blank"` attribute to an `<a>` element in my javascript but it's seems like my function disturb the element in some way and won't add it. 
**note** without the function the `target="_blank"` working fine, only when I add the animation and delay function it's disabling it.

HTML and JS:

```js
var fbId = document.getElementById('fb-id');
fbId.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  fbId.classList.add("animated", "bounceOut");
  fbId.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  e.preventDefault();
  var fbLink = fbId.href;
  setTimeout(function(url) {
    window.location = url;
  }, 1000, fbLink);
});
```

```html
<div class="col-3">
  <a id="fb-id" href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
    <img class="social-icon" id="fb-icon" src="img/fb.png" alt="facebook">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: <a> already has target="-blank" in your html..

Comment: window.location = url just navigates to the url given. It takes no account of anything related to your hyperlink, it's completely independent of that. And, as an aside, by calling that method you essentially make all the code in the preceding lines of the "click" handler pointless, because you immediately destroy the changes by loading another page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're using the wrong function - you need to use:

```
window.open("http://www.google.at", '_blank');
```

Full Code:

```
var fbId = document.getElementById('fb-id');
fbId.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  fbId.classList.add("animated", "bounceOut");
  e.preventDefault();
  var fbLink = fbId.href;
  setTimeout(function(url) { window.open(url, '_blank'); }, 1000, fbLink);
});
```

See the working JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c29u4w7o/43/ which adapts your code so that the window will be opened in a new tab.

Comment: can't understand why anyone downvoted this, it's the correct solution

Comment: Yeah they just randomly downvote answers ... the also downvote accepted anwers - I will never understand this.

Comment: Just a small note that the line `fbId.setAttribute('target', '_blank');` is now redundant

Comment: You can edit my answer :) Then you get the credits for that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your delay does not *delay* following the link.

You completely cancel the behaviour of following the link, and then assign a new value to `location`.

The `target` attribute is successfully added, but it doesn't get used because the link isn't followed (the browser is navigated via the `location` assignment instead).

If you want to navigate in a new window using JavaScript, then call `window.open()` instead of assigning to `location`.

Comment: can't understand why anyone downvoted this, it's a good explanation

Comment: because some users are strange :( always the same :(